# Remove the "Change keyboard" button in lollipop

Tags: keyboard

The button interferes with typing. My hand accidentally hits the button constantly prompting a pop up. Very annoying.

The button is in the lower right corner:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It should only show up if you have more than 1 keyboard active. Deactivate one or more keyboards.

Comment: Well one cannot disable the default Xperia keyboard on Sony, so if another keyboard installed and used, there seems to be no way of disabling this button.

Comment: Ah, disabling all keyboards including google voice typing worked on my sony after all

Comment: @Antonin I'm sure there are alternative keyboards that won't show this button -- many have it as a configurable option.